# Button.Click event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have function for slider:

```
private void slider_change(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue < 2)
        {
            this.button1.Content = "A";
            this.button1.Click += aa;
        }
        if (e.NewValue < 6 && e.NewValue > 4)
        {
            this.button1.Content = "B";
            this.button1.Click += bb;
        }
        if (e.NewValue < 10 && e.NewValue > 8)
        {
            this.button1.Content = "C";
            this.button1.Click += cc;
        }
        if (e.NewValue < 4 && e.NewValue > 2)
        {
            this.button1.Content = "D";
            this.button1.Click += dd;
        }
        if (e.NewValue < 8 && e.NewValue > 6)
        {
            this.button1.Content = "E";
            this.button1.Click += ee;
        }
    }
```

So, I have one button and 5 different functions for it. How can I delete previous handler for button1.click?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a different handler depending on the slider value, it would probably be easier to hook up a single button clicked handler, and then change what happens in that handler based on the current value of the slider. That will obviously make it much simpler to subscribe and unsubscribe to the click event, while still allowing you the flexibility to dictate what your program does for differing slider values.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.button1.Click -= ee;
```

this would de-reference from the "ee"-function

but i would prefer the method dlev suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an event handler like this is something you should not do, unless you have a very good reason to do so. 
In this case, I'd recommend creating just one event handler, and inside that event handler decide what happens next.